# Where do I change the paragraph spacing in Microsoft Outlook on macOS?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, office365, text-formatting

It's known that the macOS client of Outlook has still fallen short a bit. Yet, I still hope Microsoft simply failed in consistency here. Where can I change the spacing of paragraphs, globally? I don't find it in the option in the settings where I expect it to be, like in *Fonts* or *Composing*. Even when composing an email there is no setting to change the spacing of paragraphs in the ribbon bar:

[image: outlook settings]

Comment: For your reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/paragraph-spacing-in-outlook-for-mac/2555bdbc-28fe-4c41-af3b-67cb1fa655d7?auth=1

Comment: @Aidan Thanks, a little helpful. Via right-click > "Paragraph" I can access the spacing for the current email at least. But composing a new email will reset those settings, unfortunately. I think the Mac version just sucks, I guess.

Comment: Just as you said, it's known that the macOS client of Outlook has still fallen short a bit. Now what we can do is submit your feedback to https://outlook.uservoice.com/